# Updating ViewController UILabel from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to development and been trying to figure this out,but after trying various different solutions, I'm still unable to get the result I'm looking for.

I would like to update the UILabel in a ViewController from another class.
here is a little demo program that I cannot get to work.
I have a view controller which has 3 UILabels, one is updated from the viewDidLoad and the other two I would like to update from the other class called Hello which is called from ViewController, I can the see the class is being called correctly as the console is logging the NSLog entry but I cannot get the syntax for updating the UILabel.

Thanks in advance.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *firstLabelBox;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *secondLabelBox;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *thirdLabelBox;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Hello.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController

@synthesize firstLabelBox;
@synthesize secondLabelBox;
@synthesize thirdLabelBox;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

firstLabelBox.text=@"Hello";

[Hello updatedisplay];
[Hello getStringToDisplay];

 }
@end
```

Hello.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class ViewController;
@interface Hello : NSObject

+(void)updatedisplay;
+(void) getStringToDisplay;
@end
```

Hello.m

```
#import "Hello.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation Hello

+ (void)updatedisplay
{

 NSLog(@"NewClass - updatedisplay");
 ViewController *labelupdate02 = [[ViewController alloc]init];
 labelupdate02.secondLabelBox.text = @"Apple";
}

+ (void) getStringToDisplay
{
NSLog(@"Inside getString function - updatedisplay");
ViewController *labelupdate03 = [[ViewController alloc]init];
labelupdate03.thirdLabelBox.text = @"World";
}

@end
```

Comment: You are allocating a whole new ViewController each time.

Comment: Please have a look at NSNotification or Delegation.

Comment: i see, thanks for the quick reply. i will revisit my code.

Comment: @Larme
  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Matz   Thanks a lot for the information, those topics really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First update method of `Hello` class

```
+ (void)updatedisplay
{
    NSLog(@"NewClass - updatedisplay");    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CHANGE_SECOND_LABEL" object:nil];
}

+ (void) getStringToDisplay
{
    NSLog(@"Inside getString function - updatedisplay");    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CHANGE_THIRD_LABEL" object:nil];
}
```

And then update `viewDidLoad()`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    firstLabelBox.text=@"Hello";

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(secondLabel) name:@"CHANGE_SECOND_LABEL" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(thirdLabel) name:@"CHANGE_THIRD_LABEL" object:nil];

    [Hello updatedisplay];
    [Hello getStringToDisplay];
}
```

Implement below methods in `ViewController.m`.

```
- (void)secondLabel
{
    secondLabelBox.text = @"Apple";
}

- (void)thirdLabel
{
    thirdLabelBox.text = @"World";
}
```